# App crashes while using setContentViewController in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am making my app compatible to iOS 5 but the app crashes on the code where i have used setContentViewController.

Here is my code.

```
[[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices] setCurrentValue:[[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel]  text]];

[self.choicesPopoverController setContentViewController:[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices]];

CGFloat popoverHeight = 44.0f * [[[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices] choices] count];

[self.choicesPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(380.0f, MIN(400.0f, popoverHeight))];

if ([self.choicesPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {

    [self.choicesPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

} else {

    [self.choicesPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame]

                                                   inView:self.view

                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny

                                                 animated:YES];

}
```

here is what shared choices returns:

```
static ChoicesViewController *_sharedChoices = nil;

 +(id)sharedChoices 
   {

    if (!_sharedChoices) 

        {
        _sharedChoices = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedChoices;
    }
```

//When i comment the below code , the app wont crash in iOS 5 but the UIPopover is not shown too. And if I uncomment it it will crash in iOS 5.

```
-(UIPopoverController *)choicesPopoverController 
{
if (!choicesPopoverController) 
     {

        choicesPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self];
     }

  return choicesPopoverController;
 }
```

Comment: Does "sharedChoices" return a singleton object? It might be released somewhere and then you are trying to use it again..

Comment: i have added the sharedChoices code.

Comment: Could the controller be in use somewhere else?

Comment: what does it say in console when your app crashes? just EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt it gives "Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT"

Comment: @jbat100 but its working at its best in iOS 4, then what about iOS 5

Comment: activate zombie and try debugging. U will know the root cause of problem.

Comment: Have you done all the other things that a singleton requires (i.e. subclassing `retain`, `release` etc - see here : http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)

Comment: @deanWombourne That was a nice tutorial but no help :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution :

instead of writing

[self.choicesPopoverController setContentViewController:[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices]];

i did

choicesPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices]];

and commented out the this code

/*

```
-(UIPopoverController *)choicesPopoverController 
  {
    if (!choicesPopoverController) 
      {

          choicesPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self];
      }

   return choicesPopoverController;
 }
```

*/

Now it doesnt crash in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

You say you set breakpoints and found this line was the problem :

```
[self.choicesPopoverController setContentViewController:[ChoicesViewController sharedChoices]];
```

but there's a few things going on there. Where does it crash if you change that line to

```
id controller = self.choicesPopoverController;
id shared = [ChoicesViewController sharedChoices];
[controller setContentViewController:shared];
```

?

Comment: while going through the code and found out that there is some other issue . I have updated my question with the new code

Comment: I will give you +1 as your solution made me to find the bug, which was somewhere else.